# Is there an included or downloadable PS palette that simply displays an image for reference?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows, palette

Like the navigator but not for an open canvas, just an image needed for reference? It's not difficult to open a preview window behind PS, but I wondered if there was an integrated solution.

Also! First question ever! Glad I made it something hugely important...

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you just open the image in a new window?

Comment: I usually open reference images in photoshop and stack them inside a separate window on a separate sceen. You can just drag tab to unattach it. If that is not an option, I just place the reference images inside the same document out lf the way. Printing some of them is not bad idea either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything available to what you're asking but here are some alternatives to see other images quickly.

**Using Adobe Bridge**

This might be the closest application to what you're asking for. You can easily navigate images in Adobe Bridge and open them right away in Photoshop. Basically a file explorer that integrates with Photoshop. Just Alt+Tab (Windows) to switch programs on the fly.

**Floating Document Windows**

click on the image's tab and, with your mouse button held down, drag the tab down and away from the other tabs

**Switching Tabs From The Keyboard**

Ctrl+Tab (Windows) Command+~ (Mac)